# I can't understand part of the GoogleNet incarnation table

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[image]

as mentioned in the paper [GoogleNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4842v1.pdf) the input image of size 224x224. By calculating the following procedure I have:

- first conv $7*7+2(s)$: $((224 + 2p - 7)/2) + 1$ assuming no padding is 109.5 which is wrong
  whatever is the padding we will have a fraction because $224-7 = 217$
  and the padding is even then divided by even.
- first maxPool $3*3+2(s)$: $((112 -3)/2)+1 = 55.5$
- second conv $1*1+1(v)$ should reduce the dimension while as I see in the table it maintain the depth 64 before the conv $3*3+1(s)$ increase it into 192, is it there just to add Relu ?
- what does it mean these sympols beside the conv and maxPool $(s),(v)$?

Comment: apparently they've used padding to maintain the spatial size, and i believe s is short for stride, but Idk what is v

Comment: I did explain down the answer bu I didn't figure out yet the meaning of v and s

Comment: they mean valid and same

Comment: first maxpool doesn't contain filter.its window size is 3 *3

Comment: 1 * 1 conv with 128 filters for dimensonality reduction.so previous layer contain 64 filter and 64+128=192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only was I can answer this is by assuming that they used asymmetrical padding which results in
$((224 - 7 + 2 +3 ) /2 ) +1 = 112$ and the same applied for the pooling layer.

Regarding the second part of the conv 1x1 I only assume that they used it to add relu non-linearity in this early stage.

- v means valid
- s means same

Comment: its not asymmetrical padding